# Spring Boot Jpa mapping

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, spring-boot, inner-join

I am learning spring boot data JPA.

Here is my code
Users.java

```
    @Entity
    @Table(name = "user_Details")
    public class Users {

            @Id
            @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)

            @Column(name = "user_id")
            private Integer id;     
            @Column(name = "name")
            private String name;
            @Column(name = "password")
             private String password;

           @OneToMany(cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
           @JoinColumn(name="user_id", referencedColumnName="user_id")
            private Set<usersAction> usersAction;
```

usersAction.java

```
    @Entity
    @Table(name="user_Action")
    public class usersAction {

           @Id
           @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)

          @Column(name="action_id")
          private Integer Action_id;

           @Column(name="user_id")
              private Integer id;

           @Column(name="users_Role")
           private String usersRole;
```

UsersRepository.java

```
package com.demo.repository;

import java.util.Set;

import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.Query;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

import com.demo.model.Users;
@Repository
public interface UsersRepository extends JpaRepository<Users, Integer> {

    @Query(value="select  u.password,u.user_id,u.name,ua.users_Role from user_details as u"
            + " inner join user_action as ua"
            + " on u.user_id=ua.user_id",nativeQuery=true)
    Set<Users> findById();

}
```

UsersController.java

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/users")
public class usersController {

    @Autowired
    UsersRepository usersRepository;


      @GetMapping("/all")
        public List<Users> getAll() {
            return usersRepository.findAll();
        }

      @RequestMapping("/byid")
      public Set<Users> findByName()
      {
          Set<Users> obj1=usersRepository.findById();
            return obj1;

      }  

}
```

When I am accessing this http://localhost:8080/users/byid

I am getting output as id ,name ,password from  users_details table and also Action_id,id and users_role from users_Action

But I am expecting in Result only name from users_detail and usersRole from  users_Action table

What i need to change for that?

Comment: you need to create projections. without code, cant help

Comment: can you give me any example how to do with projections

Answer (score 0):

You need to create interfaces like this

```
interface UsersSummary {

  String getName();
   String getName();
   UsersActionSummary getUsersAction();

  interface UsersActionSummary {
    String getUsersRole();
    Integer getId();
    Integer getAction_Id();
  }
}
```

And then change your repository method to return this

```
@Query(value="select  u.password,u.user_id,u.name,ua.users_Role from user_details as u"
        + " inner join user_action as ua"
        + " on u.user_id=ua.user_id",nativeQuery=true)
Collection<UsersSummary> findById();
```

Comment: need to create two more interfaces

Comment: i am getting this error java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 2, Size: 2

Comment: sorry can't help with this. need full stack trace. update your question